# execute function with href

Tags: javascript, href, greasemonkey

I'm looking for a solution to load a function via href. `href=javascript:myFunction()` doesn't work.

The reason why I can't use onClick or an eventListener is because I want the middle mouse button to open the link I would get from the function in a new tab.

I can't put the final link directly since I need to gather the link first, and I want to do that only when the href is used.

Is this possible?

PS: This is about a tamper-/Greasemonkey script

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you can't get it to work, this works fine.

Just make sure your function is defined BEFORE the element. In your `<head>` for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/5EJuu/

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:test();">Test</a>
```

JS

```
function test() {
    alert("executed");
    return false;
}
```

---

If you are limited to after dom ready with Greasemonkey here is a work around you could use. You still need to be able to define something before the elements but not the methods.

Basically if you create a name space prior the elements you can then add methods to that name space after the document is loaded and the element will still work.

http://jsfiddle.net/5EJuu/2/

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:test.foo();">Test</a>
```

JS

```
// jsfiddle load this in the head
var test = {};

// jquery used to run on dom ready
$(function() {

    // add the method use by the element
    test.foo = function() {
        alert("executed");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like that's the problem--Greasemonkey runs after page load, right?

Comment: Ok, but there's no jQuery tag on this question.

Comment: That's an example... If Greasemonkey is used and it's already loaded after that is not needed anyway.

Comment: So is this not possible by using GM only? I'm not sure I understand. Thanks for the answer so far!

Comment: Greasemonkey has nothing to do with your issue. 

The issue is that your functions were not defined when elements where referencing them, they were defined after.

When the HTML is parsed by the browser it see the `javascript:func()` in the `href` and check if `func` is available as a function. In your case it isn't because it is defined after the browser as checked the element. It's a bit like having a `<script>` tag before and after your `<body>` if you are not familiar with `document ready`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just store the function name in any attribute and then call it in the onclick handler.

E.g. if you want this to be done on middle click with jquery you can do it like this:

html:

```
<a id='link' href='func' >link</a>
```

js:

```
$("#link").on('click', function(e) { 
    if( e.which == 2 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (typeof window[$(this).attr('href')] === "function")
            window[$(this).attr('href')]();
    }
});

function func(){
    alert('func called');
}
```

In plain js with addEventListener you can check middle mouse via `e.button` like this:

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener("click", function(e){
if(e.button == 1){
  e.preventDefault();

  if (typeof window[this.getAttribute("href")]  === "function")
            window[this.getAttribute("href")]();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need after page load

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:hello('Hello');" >link</a>
```

JS

```
hello = function(value)
{
    console.log(value)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nnb2j/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, using GreaseMonkeys `// @run-at document-start` function it is possible to actually execute GM BEFORE Page-load. 
http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at

Therefore I was able to define the function and replace the href easily.

Have a nice day